# Blender + Captivate - Transparent Flash Video

Tags: animation, transparency, video

I'm creating a captivate training module, and it would simplify some work if I could just create an animation in blender, then import it into captivate. However, I will need the video to have background transparency.

I've played around with the animation output types in blender, and some do produce transparent background video, but that turns to black in Captivate.

Any advice on the output type or workflow would be appreciated.

Comment: Quicktime (mov) files generally support transparency. Are you sure that Captivate supports video files with transparency?

Comment: It seems as though Captivate plays nicely with FLV (flash video) format files to get the transparency to work. Blender can't export FLV natively. Do you have access to any tools that could convert a Quicktime file to FLV?

Comment: As you can see from my answer the most simple workflow would be rendering straight from render in mp4 and use Miro to convert to the right codec decoder as CP do not accept the straight MP4 codec rendered from Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot render with alpha straight from blender.

Follow the steps:

• Render the frames to PNG with alpha RGBA;

• Open the images with Adobe Flash or any software that you can import the sequence of images (Handbrake,VirtualDub-1.9.11, Quicktime Pro) ;

• Use the option inside flash:

[image]

• Save to MOV with compression type like PNG;

• Encode the MOV with Adobe Media Encoder mark the encode alpha channel;

[image]

• Import the FLV generated inside Captivate, naturally your output must be SWF not HTML5.

You cannot export sound of course cause your rendering images, that´s the only solution for now!

When I use videos inside CP and my output is HTML5 I usually use the same background on the motion graphic and the CP background to make the course seamless. Like this screenshot:

[image]

And this is are a few FLV´s done using the workflow above and published as SWF (Steve Jobs moves on the grave when the word is pronounced hahaha).

[image]